# Is there a way to use fct_reorder() to reorder or easily specify the order according to 'order' column on X axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

Here, I made a plot using the data, showing corresponding 'd' values in each 'bins' ordered in a specific way.

As you can see, I have explicitly ordered them (in the ggplot code)to create the below graph.

Is there an elegant way to do the same by introducing an order, as you may see that I have introduced a column order for this sample.

I am trying to rewrite the code using **fct_reorder() from forecats package** if possible or find any other **possible elegant ways** to achieve the same result, mainly because I would like to reuse and generalise for other datasets or customised functions.

The code looks somewhat like below, I have created a sample dataset for simplicity.

```
set.seed(42)
order <- as.character(c(5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4))
seg <- as.character(c('a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c'))
bins <- as.character(c('-5% - 5%','5% - 10%','10% - 15%','15% - 20%', '>20%','<-20%','-20% - -15%','-15% - -10%','-10% - -5%'))
d <- as.numeric(sample(0:100, size = 9, replace = TRUE))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(order, seg, bins, d))

ggplot(df, aes(fill = seg, y = d, x = bins)) +geom_col()+ scale_x_discrete(limits= c('<-20%','-20% - -15%','-15% - -10%','-10% - -5%','-5% - 5%','5% - 10%','10% - 15%','15% - 20%', '>20%'))
```

**The plot generated is as follows:**

[image]

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. :)

**Changes in code:**

According to the suggestions that came in I have looked into the code and adjusted it not to use cbind(), please find the adjusted code here :

```
    set.seed(42)
order <- as.character(c(5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4))
seg <- as.character(c('a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c'))
bins <- as.character(c('-5% - 5%','5% - 10%','10% - 15%','15% - 20%', '>20%','<-20%','-20% - -15%','-15% - -10%','-10% - -5%'))
d <- as.numeric(sample(0:100, size = 9, replace = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(order, seg, bins, d)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = seg, y = d, x = bins)) +geom_col()+ scale_x_discrete(limits= c('<-20%','-20% - -15%','-15% - -10%','-10% - -5%','-5% - 5%','5% - 10%','10% - 15%','15% - 20%', '>20%'))
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `forcats::fct_relevel` if you're trying to set an arbitrary order, or `fct_reorder` and give it the order column. A bigger problem is that by calling `cbind` in the way you did, you've made all your columns into factors, so ordering by the "order" column probably *won't* work currently

Comment: I also don't get what's going on with how you created the bins—why are you making them manually and out of order? Is this something where you'll be getting bins by calling `cut` on some numeric vector? If so, they'll come out in numeric order

Comment: I created the data manually to provide the context for this question. I did not put the bins in a numeric order as it replicates the scenario with my current data. The data I have doesnt give a possibility to put the bins easily in an order, that is the very reason I had to introduce a new column 'order' to help do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the lower bound of each of the bins, convert it to numeric, and use that for ordering. The bit to fill in handling the less than and greater than signs: replace `<` with negative infinity and `>` with positive infinity.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

df_ordered <- df %>%
  mutate(lower = case_when(
    str_detect(bins, "^>") ~ Inf,
    str_detect(bins, "^<",) ~ -Inf,
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(str_extract(bins, "^\\-?\\d+"))
  )) %>%
  mutate(bins = forcats::fct_reorder(bins, lower))

df_ordered
#>   seg        bins   d lower
#> 1   a    -5% - 5%  48    -5
#> 2   b    5% - 10% 100     5
#> 3   c   10% - 15%  64    10
#> 4   a   15% - 20%  24    15
#> 5   b        >20%  73   Inf
#> 6   c       <-20%  99  -Inf
#> 7   a -20% - -15%  17   -20
#> 8   b -15% - -10%  48   -15
#> 9   c  -10% - -5%  46   -10

ggplot(df_ordered, aes(x = bins, y = d)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]